# ZSH history moves by two

Tags: zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

I use oh-my-zsh for some zsh configuration, but I have a stock installation with only `git` and `asdf` plugins.

This started happening a couple of days ago, and I don't know of anything in particular that precipitated my problems. However, now when I press the UP arrow it doesn't give me my last entry in my history file, it gives me the second to last entry. Pressing UP again gives me the 4th to last entry.

Prefacing the UP arrow with a command such as `git commit` will search through the commands that start with `git commit` but will skip items in my history as well. I suspect that I have the same zsh script running twice when I press the key, but I don't really know how I would go about finding the offending scripts.

<kbd>Up</kbd> invokes [`up-line-or-beginning-search`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Zle/up-line-or-beginning-search).

Comment: To start with, what does the `Up` key do? Run `bindkey -L | grep '\^\[[[O]A'` or press `Alt+x` then type `describe-key-briefly` and press `Enter` `Up`. This gives you a widget name. Then run the command `zle -lL` followed by the widget name to see if this invokes a function. Also check if you have an addhistory hook: `which zshaddhistory; echo $zshaddhistory_functions`

Comment: The `describe-key-briefly` method gave `"^[OA" is up-line-or-beginning-search` as the result. Running `zle -1L up-line-or-beginning-search` gave the error `zle: widgets can only be called when ZLE is active`. Googling this is very difficult and it seems like the answer is context dependent. 

`which zshaddhistory` prints `zshaddhistory not found`.

Comment: It's `zle -lL` (lowercase and uppercase ell), not `zle -1L`. `up-line-or-beginning-search` is not a built-in widget, so it's invoking a custom function which may be misbehaving. And how about `echo $zshaddhistory_functions`?

Comment: `zle -lL` returns `zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search`. `echo $zshaddhistory_functions` returns an empty line. I deleted oh-my-zsh and reinstalled and same behaviour remains.

Comment: So `up-line-or-beginning-search` is a custom widget that invokes the function of the same name. This function is shipped into zsh, so we can find its code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set -x` to enable debugging and `set +x` to disable it. With that you should be able to see what's happening in the background.

Comment: enabling debugging with `set -x` shows nothing when I press up or down